# Combining two lines with bash

Tags: linux, bash

I want to merge two lines from csv file:

```
x,,x
,x,
```

to get:

```
x,x,x
```

Can you help me?

Edit:
I have many combination of x occurence (x,, or ,x,x ...)

I give you other example. First column of file contains linux distribution name ,second column is command, if in third column exists "x" it means that command is available in centos 5, if in fourth column exists "x" it means that command is in centos 6, and if "x" is in the last field it means that is available in centos 7.

```
centos,ls,,,x
centos,ls,x,x,
```

And now I want to have one record which will summarize info about command.

Comment: Also, is the file containing only two lines? What separates each record?

Comment: File contains many lines with diffrent position of "x" in line, but I want to compare two lines at once.

Comment: It would be helpful to see a bigger chunk of expected input/output instead of just two lines.

Comment: Hi all, I wrote more details.

Comment: `File contains many lines with different...` Why are you so adamant that the readers shouldn't understand a thing? Add `centos,ls,x,x,` and `centos,ntsysv,x,x,` to the end of your file, tell me how you're planning to merge it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
sed ':a;$!N;s/,$//;s/^,//;s/\n//g;ta;s/,,*/,/g' file
```

Comment: This script doesn't do any merging at all at the moment.

Comment: @sjsam you're right, I did not try with the edit sample code. I updated.

Comment: @Kenavoz : `centos,ls,x,x,x` is the output that he wants but your second sctipt gives `centos,ls,x,centos,ls,x,x` . Read the question once more please ;)

Comment: @mona_sax Not merging ? Which is your sed version ?

Comment: I realize my mistake. @user3461823 I'm not sure that joining lines was what you wanted.

Comment: Thanks @mona_sax for your comment.